# Laravel 5 Controller Return Value not working as i want

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view, controller

I`m new to the laravel 5.4.i developed search_code controller like this.

```
public function search_code(Request $request){
    $query      = $request->search;
    $queryType  = $request->institute; // 'id' or 'name'
    $items      = DB::table('registerdetails');        

    if($queryType == 'id'){
        $items = $items->where('trainee_id', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
    if($queryType == 'full_name'){
        $items = $items->where('full_name', 'LIKE',"%$query%");
    }
    $items = $items->get();
    return view('traineeattendance.index')->with('items',$items);
}
```

What i need is $item need to be pass and get called in two different views from this controller like

```
return view('traineeattendance.index')->with('items',$items);
```

And

```
return view('traineeattendance.attendance')->with('items',$items);
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You might want to read https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: sir,can you please add me the necessary code sample it would be very appreciated.i read that but i dont understand it hope um new to the laravel.can you please do that help?

Comment: "not working as i want", because it was not made in the way you want to use it (you can't return 2 views from 1 method). Instead of trying to force things works in your way, force yourself to work in the way the tools work. Make your life easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, stop using DB facade in MVC framework unless it's very complicated query.
Create a model instead

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RegisterDetails extends Model
{
    protected $table        = 'registerdetails';
    /* Look into documentation for rest of the fields */
}
```

Then for everything you need to search create model scopes

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RegisterDetails extends Model
{
    protected $table        = 'registerdetails';

    public static function scopeTrainee($query, $input)
    {
        if(!empty($input)) {
            $query->where("trainee_id", $input);
        }
    }

    public static function scopeFullname($query, $input)
    {
        if(!empty($input)) {
            $query->where("full_name", 'LIKE', $input);
        }
    }
}
```

Simplify your controller's code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\RegisterDetails;

class RegisterDetailsController extends Controller
{   
    public $data = [];

    public function search_code(Request $request){
        if($request->institute == 'id'){
            $this->data['items'] = RegisterDetails::Trainee($request->search)->get();
        }
        if($request->institute == 'full_name'){
            $this->data['items'] = RegisterDetails::FullName($request->search)->get();
        }
        return view('traineeattendance.index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

At now the index view has items data, if you are using attendance view inside index view it will also have this data accessible.

If both index and attendance are different views (one is not included by another), then you did something wrong at design level, and you need to explain the case a little bit more

Comment: Unexplained downvote is best thing you can feel in SO community

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('items', search_code()); // this line will inject the return value of search_code() in all views in your app
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: @Thoms How this can be applied into my search_code controller given by me

Comment: I made an example, if it's still not clear I'm affraid you should first read the docs, make a small demo yourself and then try again. Best of luch though!

Answer (score -1):

use something like `view::share('variable_name', 'variable_value')`.

Your Case:

Go to AppServiceProvider on boot method add the line:
* don't  forget to import the classes

Then add the line on boot method:

```
View::share('items', search_code());
```

This will take the returned value from the method `search_code()` and make it available to all the view as `$items`

Like this: go to `AppServiceProviders.php`  on App- Providers- AppServiceProvider and add the following on boot method including the namespaces on top.

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
 use  App\Http\Controllers\YourController;

  public  function boot()
        {
            $controller = new YourController;

            View::share('items', $controller->search_code());
        }
```

Comment: sir ,can you please explain with  the code bit more please.because i dont understand what you are saying,if i know this will not a problem

Comment: @LKelmendi How can i apply this into my search_code controller?

Comment: Use View::share() when you really need to, it's heavy overkill to use it for 2 views

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek okay then show us a better way